# 'how to scan a fingerprint (using biometric) in android tablet'

Tags: android, fingerprint

"i want to scan a finger print in my android tablet with external hardware scanner which will be connected through usb to the android tablet.
i was googled and i found this link but iam not getting how this people are doing 
http://www.bioenabletech.com/fingerprint-scanner-android-tablet-mobile
and one more link which i got from googling is 
http://www.mobbeel.com/products/mobbid/overview/
is it possible to do the fingerprint scan in android tablet in any of the ways
(please don't suggest fake applications without real biometric scaning which i had already seen in google play)if possible please provide me the existing application samples and url links about this please help me on this......."

Comment: This is is too broad...Please read the FAQ before posting a question: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: please help on this did you got my question or not? iam not getting you please ......

Comment: Maybe in the far future it will be possible.

Comment: please check the edited question if you still feels the question is ambiguous and incomplete please let me know

Answer (score 3):

It is 100% imposible. no way to do it.
the hardware is not even close to be able to do that. all you can get from the screen is a grid orientation of the touch input.
you can stop looking.  the only way to do such a thing in any divice is to have a hardware component that is build for this, aka "finger scanner".  its like you ask "how can I drill a hole in a wall with my tablet using third party sdk's".

Comment: i need to find out unique identification by using fingerprint even i can connect with some of the extenal hardware with usb also please find  the below links 
http://www.bioenabletech.com/fingerprint-scanner-android-tablet-mobile http://www.mobbeel.com/products/mobbid/overview/

Comment: please some body reopen this question i was edited this question please check the links and reopen it..thanks..